# Mocking before importing in one test file is affecting another test file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

I have a class which has a side effect *at import time:* it populates a field with a value from a deployed infrastructure. It basically boils down to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66699828/96588):

```
class MyModel:
    class Meta:
        table_name = get_param("table_name")
```

I want to use instances of `MyModel` in *offline* tests, so I need to make sure that boto3 doesn't actually run the production `get_param` code. I've done it by mocking out `get_param` in these tests:

```
with patch("….get_param"):
    from … import MyModel

    def test_…
```

Clunky, but it sort of works. The problem is that if I run `pytest` with this test file first and then an acceptance test file (which *does* need to use the real `get_param`), the acceptance test ends up with a *mocked* version of `get_param` (reversing the file sequence makes both tests pass). The acceptance test runs fine on its own, but I'd rather not pull apart the test suite based on such a weird premise. Is there some way to avoid this namespace pollution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [I don't understand how Python imports work](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/8485).

Comment: you should also be mocking `prod.randint` instead of `random.randint` in order to not have to make the import happen inside that block